# difference between ReadOnly and Const?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly)

are these interchangeable? can you show me code on how you would apply the two?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555534/when-if-ever-should-we-use-const

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410723/is-there-a-difference-between-private-const-and-private-readonly-variables-in-c

Comment: @Eric, the problem with such questions is that it is easier/faster to answer them than to search for dupes. But thumbs up for searching the dupes.

Comment: eric is the man! what a wonderful asset he is to the SOF community! thank you for your service eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they aren't.

A `const` field is literal value embedded in the assembly.
Only primitive values (strings and numbers) can be `const`, and they are evaluated at compile time.
When you reference a `const` field, the compiler embeds the literal value of the field.  Therefore, if use use a `const` from another assembly, and the other assembly is recompiled with a different value, your assembly will only use the new value if you recompile it against the new version.

---

A `readonly` field is a normal field that cannot be changed outside the constructor.

Comment: answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624796/initialize-byte-array-from-a-portion-of-existing-byte-array-c

Answer (score 3):

Const can't perform evaluations whereas readonly can on initialization.  (ie you could read in a value for a readonly variable from a config file or based on some other parameter that is known at runtime, const can only be set to something known at compile time)

Answer (score 1):

A member of *any type* can be `readonly`. It simply means the member cannot be **reassigned** after the construction of the containing class; i.e., it cannot be set to a new object with the `=` operator. Mutable classes such as collections can still be modified with respect to *their* members; it's just that, if you have a `readonly` member that is a collection, it cannot be assigned to an entirely new collection after construction.

A `const` is not so different from a literal (like `5`): it represents an unchanging value and thus only really makes sense in the context of specifying a **value** (as opposed to an **object**).